# Build indoor location map with Bluetooth tracking

Tags: android, bluetooth, location, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

Hi the idea is to track multiple mobile devices location within a building, and because it's indoors, Bluetooth seems to be a better choice.

Even though Bluetooth have a short range, but because the building have a high dense of Bluetooth-enabled devices, like hundreds of them, and all in the similar area, is it possible to draw out a map to track each devices based on a network built by each Bluetooth devices?

Like put a central device in the middle as the 'server', each devices track each other's location when they are near each other, and when a device gets nearby enough to the 'server' it reports back the locations and the 'server' build a map based on the distance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ibeacon would be usefull for this idea. You can send individual device distance or other necessary infos to server, then you can map out device location, but if you trying to do this in real time i am not sure, still u may check estimote ibeacon, estimote has similar feature named indoor navigation.